# Виверн(ов)

Tags: общие-вопросы

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Виверна

Родительный падеж множественного числа: виверн или вивернов?

Склоняюсь ко второму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему же? Автор в Вашей ссылке утверждает, что wyvern выводится из латинского «vipera» (змея):"... моя виверна — опирающаяся на корень «vivi…» и, как и змея, — женского рода".

Ну, а если женского рода, то в род.п.-виверн (как серна-серн)